# Vaadin History Strange Behaviour

Tags: navigation, vaadin, browser-history

iFor a project I'm following we are experiencing a strange behaviour of the Vaadin History feature.
In particular, we have 3 views, each with a `@Route` annotation:

- `View1` with `@Route("route1", layout = MainLayout.class)`
- `View2` with `@Route(value = "route2" + "/:param1/:param2/:param3", layout = MainLayout.class)`
- `View3` with `@Route(value = "route3" + "/:param1/:param2/:param3", layout = MainLayout.class)`

When we navigate from `View1` to `View2` with `UI.navigate` and `RouteParameters` (to pass the parameters accepted from the `Route` on `View2`) we are able to use `History.back()` on `View2` to go back to `View1`.

When we navigate from `View2` to `View3` by using `UI.navigate` and `RouteParameters`, when we use the `History.back()` on `View3`, then `View1` is shown instead of `View2` (the same happens if we use `History.go(-1)`). Furthermore, if we use the browser back button from `View3`, then `View2` is correctly shown.

Could you please help or give some hint on what's happening?